# Regex HTTP Response Body Message

Tags: regex, jmeter, httprequest, http-response-codes

I use a jmeter for REST testing.
I have made a HTTP Request, and this is the response data:

```
{"id":11,"name":"value","password":null,"status":"ACTIVE","lastIp":"0.0.0.0","lastLogin":null,"addedDate":1429090984000}
```

I need just the ID (which is 11) in

```
{"id":11,....
```

I use the REGEX below :

```
([0-9].+?)
```

It works perfectly but it will be a problem if my ID more than 2 digits. I need to change the REGEX to :

```
([0-9][0-9].+?)
```

Is there any dynamic REGEX for my problem. Thank you for your attention.

Regards,
Stefio

Comment: why use a regex? is it a restriction of jmeter (I never worked with it)? the response is in JSON, you have the data ready in key - value pairs, a JSON handler would be much more fitting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any integer between `{"id":` and `,` use the following Regular Expression:

```
{"id":(\d+),
```

However the smarter way of dealing with JSON data could be [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)), going forward this option can be much easier to use against complex JSON.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") to learn more on syntax and use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the following regular expression:

```
"id":([^,]*),
```

This will first find "id": and then look for anything that is not a comma until it finds a comma.  Note the character grouping is only around the value of the ID.

This will work for ANY length ID.

Edit:
The same concept works for almost any JSON data, for example where the value is quoted:

```
"key":"([^"]*)"
```

That regular expression will extract the value from given key, as long as value is quoted and does not contain quotes.  It first finds "key": and then matches anything that is not a quote until the next quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quantifier like this:

```
([0-9]{2,}.+?)
```

It will catch 2 or more digits, and then any symbol, 1 or more times. If you want to allow no other characters after the digits, use `*` instead of `+`:

```
([0-9]{2,}.*?)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d.%2b%3f)&i=11i%2c+34%2c+566)